# Full-Sensor Nikon D750 With 4K Video

Tags: nikon, full-frame, nikon-d5000, nikon-d750

I am currently on the market for my first DSLR camera. The options I am considering are D5500 family and D750 family. The former has a cropped sensor, whereas the latter has a full sensor.

I do like the ability to take pictures using everything that a full sensor has to offer. However, I am also heavily into video and like the idea of having the 4K capability. D5500 is able to do 4K video, D750 is not.

My question is two-fold. Will there be D750 coming out anytime soon that will be capable of 4K video? More generally, how can I have this apple and eat it too? Is there anything in Nikon lineup that would allow me to do what I want and be ~$1500 or under?

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Usually, you have to pick 2 out of three: price, sensor size, and release date seem to obviously be three of them.

Comment: *Will there be D750 coming out anytime soon that will be capable of 4K video?* - bahahahahahahaha. I suggest you look into corporate espionage techniques. >_<

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 1) video has a different home at https://video.stackexchange.com and 2) it asks us to speculate about the future, and there is no way we can reasonably do that.

Comment: @Hueco Is there a SE for that? :)

Comment: MadPhysicist oh man, don't I wish. That would be epic.

Comment: A D750 with 4k video is called D850. But it may be *slightly* out of budget

Answer (score 6):

> Will there be D750 coming out anytime soon that will be capable of 4K video?

That part of the question is off-topic because [we don't deal in speculation](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/130/47295). Having said that, Nikon's big release this year was the Z6/Z7 mirrorless lineup about a month ago, so it'll probably be another year before they release a new DSLR.

> More generally, how can I have this apple and eat it too? Is there anything in Nikon lineup that would allow me to do what I want and be ~$1500 or under?

The Wikipedia page [Comparison of Nikon DSLR cameras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Nikon_DSLR_cameras) is the best resource I know for this kind of comparison. The table at the bottom uses various markup to show the features of each camera. Full frame and 4K video means that you want the D5 or the D850, and at present neither is in your budget nor likely to be easy to find secondhand.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that someone wants to buy a Rolex at a Timex price.

Comment: No. It is more like someone is trying to decide on which Rolex to buy and is trying to decide on features while having a budget.